# Integrating existing android app into your app

Tags: android

I am very much new to android development!
I saw one existing application for android which will work as a first step in my app. 
Actually a result of that application can be used as a input to my application. 
But I don't know, is it possible to integrate existing application in your application?
If yes then definitely, that should be done only by having a code for that previous application, right???

If any one have any idea, what I am asking about, Please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch any Activity from your app but in order to get result from it, you need the developer of that activity to support it.

Answer (score 0):

One example would be using "Barcode Scanner" app which is free and popular. Your app can use it by [sending Intent asking to scan and return result](http://awalkingcity.com/blog/2008/10/23/qr-codes-made-even-easier-with-android/) instead of include the library into your app. Intent mechanism is Android way to do things.