# Is it possible to connect a existing java android app with an AS3 android app?

Tags: java, android, actionscript-3

I would like to know if it's possible to get data from an already existing android application that is written in java and be used in an application that i am writing in action script. 
Basically what i want to do is for exemple when a button is pressed in my AS3 app i want it to call another app that i have written but in java have it doing his thing and then close it and have it return to the AS3 app.

Has any one done this before? Any pointers and insides are very welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any previous experience with Java or ActionScript?

Comment: I'm learning ActionScript and i need to use an app that's in java inside my actionscript app

Answer (score 0):

First of all.  Apps are a bit of a mirage in Android.  The Android OS is running and it decides which app is open or closed based on user actions like pressing home etc.

Here are some suggestions.  For communications between the apps. They could both bind to a remote service.  The remote service could be installed or request for install after one of the apps installs.  Use the remote service to allow event communication between the two apps.  When the second app finishes processing it can close out its activity, and so it does not take priority. Or you would have a viewless mode for the app.  The main activity from which the request was issued would just wait for an event back via callback.

So yes it can be done. Its just a bit of work.

Comment: Thanks for your replay i will look into the remote service solution !! i also recently found out a question here very similiar : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949069/integrating-existing-android-app-into-your-app  so i'm also going to try to see if Intent mechanism also works between java and action script